# Scroll to page section when clicking in link with #

Tags: html

I have the following HTML on the same page:

```
<a href="http://localhost:10069/en/#company">Company</a>

<section id="company" name="company" class="company">
   Company description
</section>
```

When I click the link the page scrolls to the company's section ...

But if the same link is on another page, when I click it, the home page is loaded but it is not scrolled to the company section. Why?

Comment: This can't be reproduced. Can you do it?

Comment: Is the element generated dynamically or something like that? Can you provide a demo?

Comment: it should not scroll to, it should be a jump. Maybe you have some javascript running?